# How to use wifi using python?

Tags: python, android, winapi, wifi, pywin32

I am making an windows application which would send and receive information with an **Android** phone.

I need to make use of the **wifi** to do so ( **win32api** for **python** ).

The app. would be something like this:

The android screen would show the desktop screen.
where ever you touch , a click would me made on the corresponding point on the actual desktop.
This is the most basic thing. And if I figure out to do this i will be able to do the rest.

PLEASE SUGGEST.
THANK YOU

Comment: I suggest you ask a real question.

Comment: Is there a reason you're re-inventing the VNC wheel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're playing in the wrong layer of the network. You need to get a socket connection between your phone and your computer.

Here's the documentation for [Android sockets](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html)

And here's documentation for [Python sockets](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html)